# Date format conversions Ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, date, format

There's a simple way to convert a string like "28Feb11" to a ruby date object
in this format: 28-02-2011 ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strptime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strptime/class) to create dates from arbitrary formats.

You can print out that date in your desired format with [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strftime).

```
> d = Date.strptime("28Feb11", "%d%b%y")
 => #<Date: 2011-02-28 (4911241/2,0,2299161)> 
> d.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
 => "28-02-2011"
```